# Bash script and piping

Tags: bash

I have the following simple bash script:

```
for VAR
do
   echo file found $VAR
done
```

what I want is for it to print all the files that contain the extension .png. I would expect the following command line to work, but it does not. Why?

```
ls *.png | myscript.sh
```

or

```
./myscript.sh < `ls *.png`
```

Comment: Looping on the contents of a variable is not the same as piping the results of a command to another command. The results of `ls` will be available to myscript.sh as its standard input, not as a variable.

Comment: how would you modify my script to loop the standard input?

Comment: Second calling syntax is wrong: it redirects content of the first file found to your script.

Answer (score 3):

You need `xargs`:

`ls *.png | xargs myscript.sh`

Comment: your command does not work for me. Am I missing something here?

Comment: try `[..] |xargs ./myscript.sh`, if the scritpt is not in your `PATH`.

Comment: This works because `xargs` passes its stdin to the given command as command line parameters.

Comment: The non-obvious part for me was parsing of arguments with "for".

Answer (score 3):

To read standard input script should look like:

```
while read line; do
  echo file found $line
done
```

Comment: Edited to remove the parentheses: original answer won't work because the parentheses will cause the read command to occur in a subshell, thus the variable will disappear when the subshell exits.